# Ninjaframework, Morphia and GeoSpatial indexes

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, morphia, ninjaframework

I am trying to store and query geographical coordinates in MongoDB. I am using Ninjaframework with the ninja-mongodb module, specifically using Morphia.

The entity with coordinates looks like this

```
@Entity
@Indexes({
    @Index(fields = @Field(value="coordinates", type = IndexType.GEO2DSPHERE))
})
public class Place {
    @Id
    public ObjectId id;
    public String google_places_id;
    public String name;
    public Point coordinates;
}
```

The code that creates the objects and queries them looks like this

```
try {
        List<models.lc.core.Place> lcPlaces = mongoDB.getDatastore().find(Place.class).field("coordinates").near(lat, lng).asList();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(   DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        Places places = mapper.readValue(Http.Get(url), Places.class);
        for(models.google.Place place:places.results) {
            models.lc.core.Place p = new models.lc.core.Place();
            p.name = place.name;
            p.coordinates = GeoJson.point(place.geometry.location.lat, place.geometry.location.lng);
            p.google_places_id = place.place_id;
            mongoDB.save(p);
        }
        return new Result(HttpStatus.OK_200).json().render(places);
        //return new Result(HttpStatus.OK_200).text().render(Http.dumpInputStream(Http.Get(url)));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Places response = new Places();
        response.status = url;
        return new Result(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400).json().render(e);
    }
```

I get this error message

```
"errorMessage": "error processing query: ns=core-api.PlaceTree:   GEONEAR  field=coordinates maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort:  {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query",
"errorCode": 2,
"message": "Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=core-api.PlaceTree: GEONEAR  field=coordinates maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server localhost:27017",
"localizedMessage": "Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=core-api.PlaceTree: GEONEAR  field=coordinates maxdist=1.79769e+308 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query' on server localhost:27017",
"suppressed": []
```

I have tried to call mongoDB.ensureIndexes(true); which does create the index on coordinates. But I still get the error I pasted above.

The internet provides no help, I hope someone out there can.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: After manually creating the index it works, so the problem lies in the creation of the annotated index - i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you file an [issue](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues) with index definition created by morphia and the one you created by hand?  If morphia is creating bad indexes, i'd like to get that fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will file an issue asap.